# Show $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=(1+\cos x)(x+\sin x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Show $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}=(1+\cos x)(x+\sin x)$ given $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=x+\sin x$.

Thought it would just be $(1+\cos x)$.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt} f(x) = \frac{df}{dx}(x)\times\frac{dx}{dt}$

Comment: Hint: Chain Rule.

Comment: by the way, functions in latex should be written, for example, `\sin x` as opposed to `sin x`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The derivative of $x$ is $1$ *with respect to x*. But $\frac{d}{dt}x$ is simply $\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Thus we have $\frac{d}{dt}(x+\sin x)=\frac{dx}{dt}+\cos(x)\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}$

and since $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is given we have $(x+\sin x)+(\cos x)(x+\sin x)=(x+\sin x)(1+\cos x)$

Answer (score 4):

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=x+\sin x
$$
$$
\frac d {dt}\  \frac{dx}{dt} = \underbrace{\frac d {dt} (x+\sin x) = \left( 1+\cos x \right) \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}}_\text{chain rule} = (1+\cos x)(x+\sin x).
$$

Maybe you're confusing "$dt$" in the denominator with "$dx$".  It would be quite correct to say
$$
\frac d {dx}(x+ \sin x) = 1+\cos x.
$$
But $x$ is a function of $t$, and just which function of $t$ it is, is something we're not explicitly told.  And we're differentiating with respect to $t$, not with respect to $x$.